# Control Maps Net Maui (.Net 8.0) for Windows

Tags: .net, maui

I'm working with .Net 8.0 and I would like to use the `Maui.Controls.Map`.

The code in **MauiProgram.cs** file is :

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                })
                .UseMauiMaps(); 
            return builder.Build();
        }
```

The code for my view is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mapas="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps"
             x:Class="Test.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="Gray">
   
    <ScrollView>
            <mapas:Map x:Name="mapa"
                   Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

When I run he app in Windows I get this error:

> Handler not found for view Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Map.

Do I need to do something else or is it that I can't use this control in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-8.0)

> The Map control isn't supported on Windows due to lack of a map
> control in WinUI. However, the CommunityToolkit.Maui.Maps NuGet
> package provides access to Bing Maps through a WebView on Windows. For
> more information, see Get started.